# I2C issue on Raspi 4 running Raspbian

Tags: robotics, raspberry-pi4

I am running a Raspi4 with a HAT board to attach Grove attached components (Adeept's Mars Rover Picar-B kit).  I have had it succesfully up and running with remote access a couple of times.  I believe my SD card was corrupted due to improper shutdown, so I re-imaged and started over again.  Now I am getting this error message:

RuntimeError: Could not determine default I2C bus for platform.

I have never seen this before.  Is this a hardware issue, or can it be fixed on the software end?

Comment: just to be clear, I do have the I2C setting enabled on my Raspi setup

Comment: As it is (probably) not a programming problem your question might be better suited [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)

Comment: thank you Bill, I will try there